# WorkManager Worker class not running after App kills

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-jetpack, android-intentservice

I am extending the `Worker` class and in its `doWork()` method I'm uploading files to the cloud. The app uploads files when it is in foreground, but If I kill the app the `doWork` process stops. After opening the app again, it starts to run and completes the task. This means it was not running in the background. I want to run a worker thread even if  app is not in the foreground. Should I add something into the manifest file or any flag to the `Activity`. Any help will be appreciated.

The `dowork()` method can be called from the `uploadworker` instance.

```java
OneTimeWorkRequest uploadworker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(VideoUploadWorker.class)
    .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadworker);
```

This code is working perfectly when app is in foreground. I tested in many devices but I got same results.

Comment: which device are you using ?

Comment: I use it with a foreground service, themes like the only way to make it run in background. But even this way without acquiring wakelock, it will suffer from doze mode

Comment: @Quicklearner I tested in Samsung,Pixel and infocus & api level 23,26,27

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can u please elaborate how to combine Worker class and foreground service.

Comment: you don't need to combine them in fact. You need to run the foreground service to prevent your app from being killed.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks for your suggestion.I will try this

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko It is not working

Comment: what exactly? Service?

Comment: I write Service with retruning Sticky intent and startcommand method i start the worker class.in workerclass dowork method i am uploading file.But when i close the app file not uploading

Comment: that is not enough to start foreground service. You need not just a service, but a foreground service

Comment: public class VideoUploadService extends Service {


    Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        OneTimeWorkRequest uploadworker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(VideoUploadWorker.class)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadworker);

        Log.i("Service","StartCommand");

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

Comment: Have you found a real answer?  I am wondering the same.

Comment: If you are already using a foreground service, why use WorkManager for one time, why not just do it with the service itself? It might help if you can include the code for your foreground service.